# Does Excel evaluate both result arguments supplied to the IF function?

Tags: excel, if-statement, lazy-evaluation

Excel's `if` function takes three arguments, a condition, an if-true value, and an if-false value.  Does Excel work out the value of all three arguments, or does it only work out the value of the condition and the corresponding result?

**Clarification:** I'm not wondering what the *result* of the `if` will be, I'm wondering whether or not it calculates the value of all arguments before calculating the result of the function.

This is equivalent to asking whether or not the `if` function uses lazy or strict evaluation.  For example, the following pseudocode:

```
x = 5;
print x>2 ? "Bigger" : "Smaller" + 1/0
```

would throw a divide-by-zero exception in a language with fully strict evaluation, as it would evaluate the `1/0`, even though the result wouldn't be required for the `?:` operator.

In a lazy-evaluation language, the `?:` operator would evaluate `x>2` before even deciding which expression to evaluate.

The problem is that in Excel, `1/0` produces a legitimate value (which happens to be `#DIV/0!`) that can exist in expressions.  Therefore, simply calling `=if(true,1,1/0)` doesn't show whether Excel is evaluating the `1/0` or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very east to test

```
? iif(true, 1, 1/0) 'run-time error: division by zero
```

I'm assuming you really mean iif() - in VBA this does not "short-circuit", so you should use `If..Then..Else..End If` in cases where that could be a problem.

Ok - testing what you really asked:

```
'In a VBA module
Function TruePart()
      MsgBox "True part"
      TruePart = "True"
End Function


Function FalsePart()
      MsgBox "False part"
      FalsePart = "False"
End Function
```

In a cell: `=IF(TRUE,truepart(),falsepart())`

Only get one msgbox per calculation of the IF() cell.

As further validation, this gives you two msgbox - one for each:

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print IIf(True, TruePart(), FalsePart())
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm actually talking about the Excel function `if`, not the Excel VBA statement `if`.

Comment: Awesome!  I wouldn't have guessed you could use `Msgbox` in a `Function`.

Comment: Nice, but this may be due to Excel taking a special approach when it comes to calling VBA, since macros, unlike native functions, may cause side effects. IMO, the answer to this question remains unknow, since I don't know of any such test with native functions that was conclusive.

Comment: @AndréNeves - typically UDF's in Excel are restricted so as *not* to cause side-effects, so I'm not sure that Excel treats UDF's differently in this respect.  Then again I'm not sure it doesn't.  If you can think of a way to test this it would be interesting to determine which way it goes.

Comment: I think we're unclear on the meaning of *side effects*. This is what I mean: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science). It would be strange if the false branch of an if statement *modified another cell* (side effect), for example, so that's why I think Excel **might** treat them differently in this regard. A way to test it would be `=IF(TRUE, 1, VerySlowNativeFunction())` and seeing if it takes time, but I can't find such slow Excel function - it's all virtually instantaneous.

Comment: Ok, I did it. I made Excel invert a huge matrix (80x80 I think) of random numbers. It took some seconds. Then I used my approach `{=IF(TRUE, 1, MINVERSE(range))}`. It was instant. So, to me, it's settled: Excel does not evaluate all arguments.

Answer (score 5):

It does not.

Excel 2013 only evaluates the necessary code.

I had a very complex and time consuming cell formula to copy through a couple hundred thousand rows. It would take a few hours to calculate. But fortunately, it was easy to determine based on some other criteria when the result would be zero.

So using an If Statement to avoid the calculation when other criteria suggested it must be zero, and performing the calculation only when necessary sped up the process immensely, cutting processing time to about 10% of the previous.

If Excel were evaluating both expressions, the If Statement would only have added complexity and time.

Answer (score 3):

A couple simple tests:

`=IF(TRUE,1,1/0)`

`=IF(FALSE,1/0,1)`

Neither results in a div/0 error, so one could conclude only the corresponding result of the condition is actually evaluated. Obviously the condition itself also must be evaluated.

In more complex formulae you could also use the Evaluate Formula tool to watch how `IF` statements are parsed.

Comment: Interesting difference between my answer and @Doug Glancy. I used XL2007.

Comment: Excel could still be calculating the `1/0`, then returning the other argument as the result of the function.

Comment: Our 2nd formulas are different.  Mine evaluates to False and so yields the error.  Our results are the same.

Comment: Sorry I misread Doug's 2nd formula. More evidence of lazy evaluation: Watch `=IF(TRUE,"sucess",IF(TRUE,0/0,LOG(-1)))`, the expressions in the nested `IF` are never evaluated.

Comment: +1 for the mention of Evaluate Formula, which is the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Excel seems to use eager evaluation for the `IF()` function (i. e. always evaluates all three arguments). To test without VBA, turn on automatic workbook calculation and enter into a new workbook's cell:

```
=IF(TRUE, 0, RAND())
```

Save and close workbook. Open the workbook again and close again, and Excel will show the "save changes" prompt because volatile function `RAND()` has been evaluated.

Change `RAND()` to `1` and Excel does not show the prompt.

Comment: This is not a proof. In my opinion, this is what happens: Excel recognize that the cell has a formula containing a ***volatile*** function (`RAND()`), so it recalculates the formula and thus prompt you to save the workbook.

Comment: Maybe not proof, but an interesting example relevant to my interests.  I have an `=IF(TRUE,RtdServerCall(server,port,topic1,topic2,topic3),"")` in my spreadsheet and I'm trying to determine if IF uses strict or lazy evaluation semantics.  RtdServerCall must be considered **volatile**

Answer (score 0):

I have the opposite answer to Tim, based instead on XL 2010 If Function:

```
=IF(TRUE,1,1/0)
```

doesn't yield a #DIV/0 error,

```
=IF(FALSE,1,1/0)
```

does.  Also, [my reading](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx) implies that only the appropriate condition is evaluated.

Comment: This doesn't actually say whether Excel calculates `1/0` first.  It could be evaluating all arguments, leading to `IF(TRUE,1,#DIV/0)`, then evaluating the function.

Comment: @Joe, that's true.  The link, while not definitive, refers to evaluation of the met condition, which kind of implies that the unmet isn't evaluated.  I can't find anything more definitive.  Where's Charles Williams?