# Excel VBA - Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble finding the cause of the

> Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

that occurs on the last line of the table I am manipulating.

I have tried different tables of the same format and have found that they work just fine. This leads me to believe there is an issue with the specific row in the table

Relevant code:

```
    VName.Value = RID.Value & " " & IIf(InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) <> 0 And _
    (InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) - 1) >= 10, _
    Left(RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) - 1), RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value)
```

Full Code:

```
'~~~> For Each Row
'~~~> ID Row (offset by 2 columns) with SectionTitle (Cache A3) + ID starting with 0 on the header
Set RID = Nothing
Set SecT = Range("'Values'!$A$3")
Set RCount = .Range(.Cells(HC, 2), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
IDCount = 0

For Each RID In RCount
    'ID Req rows
    RID.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value = SecT.Value & " " & IDCount
'~~~> Add ID, ReqName, Section to Values sheet where if ID is 0 then Type = Folder
        Set VSection = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
        VSection.EntireRow.ClearContents
        Set VName = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)
        Set VType = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4)
        Set VID = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5)
    'Row = Header where IDCount = 0
        If IDCount = 0 Then
        VSection.Value = SecT.Value
        VName.Value = SecT.Value
        VType.Value = "Folder"
        VID.Value = IDCount
    'Row <> Header where IDCount > 0
        ElseIf IDCount > 0 Then
        VSection.Value = SecT.Value
        VName.Value = RID.Value & " " & IIf(InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) <> 0 And _
        (InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) - 1) >= 10, _
        Left(RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) - 1), RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value)
        VName.WrapText = False
        VID.Value = IDCount
        End If
    IDCount = IDCount + 1
Next RID
```

`RID.Value = FLO.1170`
`RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value = WORKITEM MANAGEMENT`

triggers a

> Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

As there are no line breaks within "WORKITEM MANAGEMENT" it should use the full cell value and not the Left function. The other 113 rows worked fine.

Comment: It would seem that the `IIF` is evaluating both of the conditions, not ignoring the second when the first is false. If *<something>* And *<something else>* always evaluates both. If *<something>* then If *<something else>* only evaluates the second if the first is true. I suspect that the second criteria is causing the crash because it is being evaluated regardless of whether the first is true or not (in this case *not*) and `Left` cannot have a negative length. Change the IIF to a pair of nested If statements.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440104/does-excel-evaluate-both-results-of-the-if-function/10440279#10440279

Comment: @ssoong - See my expanded explanation and an alternative using `.Split` below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It would seem that the IIF is evaluating both of the conditions, not ignoring the second when the first is false. If  And  always evaluates both. If  then If  only evaluates the second if the first is true. I suspect that the second criteria is causing the crash because it is being evaluated regardless of whether the first is true or not (in this case not) and Left cannot have a negative length. Change the IIF to a pair of nested If statements.
2. It also appears that you're are trying to compare `Left(<string>, <length>)` to the number *10*. This may not be correct. If text that looks like a number is being returned out of the [Left method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left(v=vs.110).aspx) then wrap it in CLng() or CDbl() to get an actual number.
3. Perhaps a [.Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) would be a better choice. If Split cannot find the delimiter to actually split something, you will still have the original value as the zero-based element.

   `VName.Value = RID.Value & " " & Split(RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, Chr(10))(0)`

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a .split function. Brilliant, thank you.