# Is Excel's 'Dependency-Chain' increased or decreased?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula which includes the use of a UDF that calculated National insurance liability (a tax in the UK). It is complex and use many times, so it is slow to calculate.

Some of the cells it gets the salary from are unused, and so have zeros in.

is the formula:

```
=NI_Calc(D9,A1:A5,B1:B5,F1:F5)
```

better than:

```
=IF(D9=0,0,NI_Calc(D9,A1:A5,B1:B5,F1:F5))
```

i.e. does the IF function instruct Excel not to calculate the UDF 'NI_Calc'? thereby reducing the load.

or does Excel calculate the UDF anyway and the IF function just adds to its load?

Thanks

Comment: If the If is not false then the NI_Calc is not calculated. You can observe this with the [Evaluate Formula](https://goo.gl/Vl25be) command. In nested Ifs with multiple conditions, putting the rarest first improves calculation efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

the IF statement in excel will not calculate the second part of the statement if the first part satisfies the condition. From the docs...

"When Excel finishes evaluating the first condition, the results may match (in which case the Approve result appears) or they may not. If it's not a match, the parent IF function has already run through two of its three arguments. You still have two possible outcomes! You complete your formula by nesting your second IF function in the third argument (value_if_false) of the parent IF. The nested IF becomes the self-contained third argument of the parent IF. When the nested IF finishes evaluating, it decides between the two remaining possible outcomes, displays the result, and the function ends."

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

EDIT: Actually, thats not really massively clear...

this answer [Does Excel evaluate both result arguments supplied to the IF function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440104/does-excel-evaluate-both-results-of-the-if-function) shows it better